# How to get the specific field of foreignkey using values function in Django?

Tags: django-models

Suppose Foo, Entry are two Django models, and foo is a foreignkey in Entry. 
The Django QuerySet Api says that,If you have a field called foo that is a foreignkey, the default values() call will return a dictionary key called foo_id( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets).  My question is how to get the specific field of foreignkey foo by values()? That is, if FIELDS is a field of fool,when I get a dictionary list of Entry, how to show FIELDS in the return dictionary, not the foo_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double underscores to denote a field of a foreign key:

```
Entry.objects.values('foo__FIELDS')
```